# Facebook Ads SDK integration changing existing project configuration

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin, ads

I have written an app using Kotlin which has all integration which uses Fragment/Activity. Now I'm integrating [Facebook Ads SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/app-setup), but as soon dependency get sync, application code started to throw compilation error on building.

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

Most of these are relate with how kotlin null assertion I have used across application. PFA. [image]

[image]

Any chance FB SDK changed default property but how come that is possible though this has added as external SDK.

Any suggestion what is issue & how can this be fixed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got fix for this. This was issue with dependent lib version mis matching, it was different in my app project & FB SDK. There is well directed solution propose **[here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/customizing_dependency_resolution_behavior.html)**

And I modified it as per my need, In following case both app & added 3rd part libs will use same version 26.1.0.

```
// Configuration need to align & force FB SDK to use app using version which is 26.1.0.
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            details.useVersion "26.1.0"
        }
    }
}
```